# How do i insert using mongoid and not having to do an extra query?

Tags: mongoid

Is there any way I can prevent from having to query the db for the question when I do this.

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :followed_questions,  class_name: 'Question', inverse_of: nil
qid = "501928374"
q = Question.find(qid)
self.followed_questions << q unless self.followed_questions.include?(q)
self.save
```

I want to do this:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :followed_questions,  class_name: 'Question', inverse_of: nil
qid = "501928374"    
self.followed_questions << qid unless self.followed_questions.include?(qid)
self.save
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do by assigning ids not documents

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :followed_questions,  class_name: 'Question', inverse_of: nil
qid = "501928374"    
self.followed_question_ids << qid unless self.followed_question_ids.include?(qid)
self.save
```